# jenkins rvm plugin issues

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, rvm, jruby

I have a Jenkins job setup on ubuntu.  I tried using rvm use in the bash shell but it says i needed to envoke /bin/bash --login in order to use the shell script.  So i tried adding that to the top of my shell script but it still failed.  So to google I went and found an RVM plugin for Jenkins.  I configured the plugin for jruby 1.7.4 but now I get a whole new error:

```
Capturing environment variables produced by 'rvm use jruby-1.7.4'
$ bash -c export
$ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
$ bash -c "test -f /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
[workspace] $ bash -c " source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create jruby-1.7.4 && export > rvm.env"
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson661746741998327634.sh
+ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
+ jruby -S cucumber
/home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson661746741998327634.sh: 3: /home/nwssc/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/temp/hudson661746741998327634.sh: jruby: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So what is the proper way of doing this on ubuntu?  I have successfully deployed this on windows, but RVM and Jenkins don't seem to play nice.  I need to intercept the cucumber command and export the JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8 as well.

Comment: check if `jruby` command exists in the installation: `ls -l  /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin/*ruby*`

Comment: @mpapis I will check that dir when I get to work, but I have successfully launched it from the terminal.